# JS/JQuery: Dynamically add "pattern" and "title" attribute to form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have multiple form input elements.  I would like to add a `pattern` attribute and a `title` attribute to each one, but rather than do so manually, I want to dynamically add the same `pattern` and `title` to each form input using JavaScript/jQuery.

This is what the form input fields look like now:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="paycheck" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="investments" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="otherIncome" />
```

As an end result I would like each form input to look like the following:

```
<input pattern="\d*\.?\d*" title="blah blah blah" type="text" class="form-control" id="paycheck" />
etc...
```

As examples, I've tried the following for the pattern attribute, but none of them work:

```
$( "input" ).attr("pattern", '\d*\.?\d*');
$( "input" ).attr("pattern",  \d*\.?\d* );
$( ".formClass input" ).attr("pattern", '\d*\.?\d*');

$( "input" ).prop("pattern", '\d*\.?\d*');
$( "input" ).prop("pattern",  \d*\.?\d* );
$( ".formClass input" ).prop("pattern", '\d*\.?\d*');

...imagine something similar for the title attribute...
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/b8RmX/

Comment: hmm, you're right... that's odd...

Comment: Of course, a pattern is really only useful for required elements in a form that is validated.

Comment: Do the elements need to be required?

Comment: add the pattern attr to your initial elements. Other wise .attr will not add the attribute itself. `set one or more attributes for every matched element.`. Just leave the attr blank like `pattern=""` on the input elements.

Comment: @Ronburgundy That's part of my question.  I don't want to have to manually add in `pattern=""` to each element.  I want to have JS add it in.

Comment: It appears that .attr should do that, not sure why its not for you. Possibly the browser you are testing on? idk.

Comment: The attribute will be added even if it's not there to begin with, and yes, for the form not be submitted and the HTML5 validation to kick in, the elements must be required.

Comment: @adeneo I finally got it working.  It actually was an error somewhere else in the code.  However, you're wrong about the required fields.  None of my fields are required, and only if I input incorrect text will the HTML5 validation throw an error.  If I inlude the correct text in one field and leave the other fields empty, no error is thrown.  I haven't done research on it, but that is what is happening right now for me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end, I found that the syntax was correct.  There was an error somewhere else in the code preventing that statement from being run.  Just goes to show that you should always make sure everything is good elsewhere in your code first.

However, I did learn a few things from this which I will note for others:

1. The jQuery `.attr()` function will dynamically add any attribute you specify, so you don't need to put `pattern=""` in your form elements first in order for the value to be added or changed.
2. Of important note, if you are going to dynamically add a regex using jQuery, YOU NEED TO ESCAPE certain characters.

The regex was originally `\d*\.?\d*` but in the DOM it was showing up as `d*.?d*` so when sending the regex through jQuery I escaped the backslashes like so: `\\d*\\.?\\d*`.

1. Finally, I did not have to make my fields required for the regex to work.  The HMTL5 validation only threw an error for me if I included incorrect text in the field, and when it threw an error, the form was not submitted.  If I left the fields empty or put correct text in the fields, then no error was thrown.  I'm up for an explanation if I'm wrong.

Comment: The regular expression `\d*\.?\d*` matches zero or more digits then zero or one full stop then zero or more digits - so an empty string (or a single full stop character) will be matched by it and be a valid input. If you want to make it so a number is required then use `\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+` which will match numbers in with various formats including: `01234` or `01234.` or `012.34` or `.01234` but will not match an empty string or a single full stop character.

Comment: @MT0 Perfect.  Thanks.  I didn't even realize just a full stop worked.  You're regex works even better.

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character for both strings and regular expressions and you are passing a string to `.attr()` for use in a regular expression then you need to escape the escape character (i.e. use `\\ `) in the string so it will still be present in regular expression. You can see the same if you compare the two different ways of declaring a regular expression in JavaScript: using a regular expression literal `/\d+/` vs. passing a string to the constructor of the `RegExp` object `new RegExp( '\\d+' )` - both create the same RE but you need to double escape the string but not the literal.

Comment: The issue I was having was due to the backslashes. I escaped them by doubling them and that solved my issue.