# Jquery Add HTML5 Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add all required fields attribute (pattern and title) through jQuery, but it failed to read the pattern properly. Not sure why though?

https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/a7bt6tyr/3/

```
<form>
<!--<input pattern=".*\S+.*" title="This field is required" required>-->
<input required>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$(function(){
  $('form').find('input').each(function(){
        if( $(this).prop('required') ){
            $(this).attr({
                'pattern': '.*\S+.*',
                'title' : "This field is required"
            })
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Same question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20447467/2565294

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\` doesn't mean the same thing for a regex and a string. Escape it, if you want to add it to your property.

```
$(function(){
      $('form').find('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('required')){
            $(this).attr({
                'pattern': '.*\\S+.*',
                'title' : "This field is required"
            });
        }
    });
});
```